# What is ろくなもんじゃない referring to?

Tags: meaning

In the below passage I am a bit unsure of what the character is saying when he says ろくなもんじゃない. Before this passage the character has woken up from a nightmare and reflected on the events that have lead him to where he is now.

Originally I was thinking that ろくなもんじゃない was referring to his father, however on second thought I'm not quite sure this is correct. The fact that he can't even really remember his father in the first place and the previous sentence where he uses the phrase ろくでなし make me think this ろくなもんじゃない is referring to something else.

> しかしまあ、見事な脱線人生である。どこで、どうして、まっとうな道を外れたのか？これと言って怒りをぶつける対象はなかったが、強いて言えば父親という人なのだろう。とはいえ、飲む打つ買うの三拍子揃ったろくでなしならともかく、殴る顔も覚えていないと来ている。一体、どこで何をしているやら。寝よ……**ろくなもんじゃない**。無理矢理、目を閉じる。

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see, this ろくなもんじゃない is addressed to no one in particular. As you said, the speaker doesn't remember the face of his father. This ろくなもんじゃない is just "dammit", and he is cursing his 脱線人生 itself.